# how can find the largest number and null if array empty

Tags: android, arrays, kotlin

fun indexOfMax(a: IntArray): Int? {
    return 0
}

link to task 
https://try.kotlinlang.org/#/Examples/Problems/Index%20of%20Maximum/Index%20of%20Maximum.kt

---

my try :

```
fun indexOfMax(a: IntArray): Int? {

 var max = 0
 for (i 0..lastIndex){
 e = a[i]

 if (e > max){
  e = max 
  }
}
return max
}
```

Answer (score 3):

In Kotlin you can do it in one line of code.

If you are looking for the max element or null if the array is empty:

```
return  array.max()
```

If you are looking for the index of the max element or null if the array is empty:

```
return array.max()?.let { array.indexOf(it) }
```

In the given problem you need to look for the last index:

```
return array.max()?.let { array.lastIndexOf(it) }
```

The source code of the functions:

```
/**
 * Returns the largest element or `null` if there are no elements.
 */
public fun IntArray.max(): Int? {
    if (isEmpty()) return null
    var max = this[0]
    for (i in 1..lastIndex) {
        val e = this[i]
        if (max < e) max = e
    }
    return max
}
```

And

```
/**
 * Returns first index of [element], or -1 if the array does not contain element.
 */
public fun IntArray.indexOf(element: Int): Int {
    for (index in indices) {
        if (element == this[index]) {
            return index
        }
    }
    return -1
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If i want to find the maximum number from a list of longs..

```
ArrayList<Long> CallsTimes = new ArrayList<>();
Long HighestTimeOfCall;

HighestTimeOfCall = Collections.max(CallsTimes);
```

---

In your case it just should be `ArrayList<Int> CallsTimes = new ArrayList<>();` HighestTimeOfCall should be int.

---

```
if(CallsTimes.size() > 0)
{
  // Its empty array list show error or do something else
}
else
{
  // find max int as shown above
}
```